# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException while trying to type a text inside a popup

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

This is my code : 
public void Addinvolvedparties() throws InterruptedException {

```
    String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your
                                                            // parent window
    String subWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window
                                                        // handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
     Thread.sleep(5000); // perform operations on popup

    driver.findElement(
            By.id("ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucAddEditInvolvedParty_txtIntPerson"))
            .sendKeys("sa");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler); // switch back to parent
                                                    // window

}
```

I am clicking on a popup and I'm entering the text for a text field, in the code i have given the id of the text field and I am sending keys. But its throwing an error saying `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`. I have to make this work on IE10, and the application supported only on IE. After opening the window i need to use the autosuggest feature , but it isnt recognizing the id

Comment: How are you initializing your IEDriver?

Comment: Could you please provide HTML code of popup window?

Comment: <input type="text" style="width:200px;background-color:;" onkeydown="javascript: return AEIP_doEscapeNw('ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucAddEditInvolvedParty_thePersonsDiv','ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucAddEditInvolvedParty');" onkeyup="javascript: AEIP_doTheTypeAheadNw(this,'ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucAddEditInvolvedParty_thePersonsDiv','ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucAddEditInvolvedParty');" autocomplete="off" class="input1" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ucAddEditInvolvedParty_txtIntPerson" maxlength="110" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceholder$ucAddEditInvolvedParty$txtIntPerson">

Comment: @Arran :  DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
  File file = new File("C:\\selenium-java-2.39.0\\selenium-2.39.0\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.41.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
  ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
  ieCapabilities.setCapability("initialBrowserUrl", baseUrl)
  ieCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities)

Comment: @user3548850, it's probably because of the `INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGN‌​ORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS` and `ignoreZoomSetting` capabilities you are setting.